# Add an event outside of calendar with fullcalendar

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am using `fullcalender` library to make a big calendar for my project, in their documentation as far as I see, I can only add events by clicking `on` the empty dates in calendar. But I am trying to add a button `outside` of a calendar which will show a popup when clicked and user can add an calendar event. I can just create a button outside of calender and call a function like

```
  function handleAddEvent () { 

     // how do I get selectionInfo here ?
  }

<>
 <button onClick={handleAddEvent}>Add an event to calender</button>
        <FullCalendar
          plugins={[
            dayGridPlugin,
            timeGridPlugin,
            interactionPlugin,
            listPlugin,
          ]}
          ...
         />
 </>
```

but I can't find a way to get the [selectionInfo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) ( is a plain object with the following properties) as it comes from `<FullCalendar>` and it is necessary to add an event to a calendar. Are there any workarounds for this ? Thanks in advance.

You can see my code sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-wing-sgn3y?file=/src/App.js)

**UPDATE**

I used [customButtons](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/customButtons) to create an external button to get necessary information from user and add an event along with `useRef` as `calendarRef.current.getApi()` to use `addEvent` to create an event. My codes will be

```
 <FullCalendar
            plugins={[
              dayGridPlugin,
              timeGridPlugin,
              interactionPlugin,
              listPlugin,
            ]}
            ref={calendarRef}
            headerToolbar={{
              left: "prev,next today customAddEventBtn",
              center: "title",
              right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek",
            }}
            initialView="dayGridMonth"
            customButtons={{
              customAddEventBtn: {
                text: "Add an event",
                click: handleCustomAddEventBtn,
              },
            }}
    />
    
  function handleCustomAddEventBtn() {

    let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi();

    if (title) {
      calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection
      calendarApi.addEvent({
        id: uuidv4(),
        title,
        start: selectedFromDate, // state to get date form user
        end: selectedToDate, // state to get date form user
        allDay: true,
      });
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: `how do I get selectionInfo here ?`...you don't. If you want to have an external button, then you need to ask the user for all the information you need to create the event, such as start and end date. And then you feed that directly to the calendar via the [addEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent) method. You don't _need_ selectionInfo - you can't pass a selectionInfo object back into fullCalendar in order to create an event. selectionInfo is provided _to you_ when the user makes a selection. You then decide what to do with that info...

Comment: ...but if you don't want to use the selection feature, then you don't need selectionInfo, instead you gather the information you need by a different method, however you choose to implement that in your own UI/code.The fields you can use which fullCalendar recognises are described in the [event parsing](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) documentation. It says all the fields are optional but realistically it makes sense to supply at least a title and a start date.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't see about `customButtons` when I checked their documentation first, I guess I will collect all necessary information from user and use `customButtons` and `addEvent` to add events.